# How to log the details about the devices connected to my Pi Access Point

Tags: access-point, logfiles

I have already configured my Raspberry Pi as an access point. I, now, need to see/log the details about the devices which had connected to my Pi.

My **use case** is to configure a metered connection through my Pi, i.e., each device which connects to my Pi should only be allowed a fixed amount of data to use (both upload and download) per day, say 1 GB per day. After the connected device exhausts this limit, it might be given access to the Pi's network on a subscription model.

The logged details should include:

- the IP given to the connected device by the DHCP server
- the MAC address of the device (planning to use this attribute to uniquely identify the device and calculate its data usage over multiple sessions in a day)
- Amount of data uploaded/downloaded per session
- Details about each session, for each device, in a day

I want my device to automatically start logging these details without any human intervention. So, I assume that I need to do this using a script which has to be configured to run on startup. Any pointers on how to achieve this will be appreciated.

I hope I have succeeded in explaining the question clearly. Thanks!

Comment: What tool are you using for your 802.11 daemon ? and for the dns/dhcp ? The IP addr, hostname, macaddr, timestamp... can be found into the 'leases' file (one client per line). For the  `data uploaded/downloaded per session` you must have a network sniffer (ex: wireshark with a filter for a specific network). Then use wireshark for show `ALL` informations about the network (use filtered IP of specific client).  Example of another related network tool (ex: [darkstat](https://packages.debian.org/en/sid/net/darkstat))

Comment: @Ephemeral Sorry, I did not understand your question: What tool are you using for your 802.11 daemon ? and for the dns/dhcp ?

I followed the steps at <https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md>. I hope this answers your query. 

Using Wireshark is not what I am interested in. Isn't there any service available in Raspbian platform to get the stuff done?

Comment: Not be sorry, what program are you using for create the access point (hostapd?) and what program are you using for the dhcp server (isc-dhcp-server, dnsmasq?) ?

Comment: @Ephemeral With the hints in your comment, I am in a better position to answer. For access point, it is `hostapd`. For dhcp server, it is `dnsmasq`. The static IP is configured using `dhcpcd`.

Comment: Ok then your are using hostapd and dnsmasq. For the clients informations you can parse the 'leases' file of dnsmasq in `/var/lib/misc/dnsmasq.leases` ([output example](https://linux-tips.com/t/dnsmasq-show-ip-lease-information/231)) if you have not specified your own file in dnsmasq.conf. For network I don't know without sniffing the traffic.

Comment: Sorry, but no, you are using dnmasq for the dhcp only. For dhcpd service in same time it is not possible because dnsmasq is configured for dhcp server and then listen on the network dhcp default port :67.